# connection between a participial phrase and the main clause

Tags: present-tense, participles

A coworker wrote the following sentence, but I wonder what connection there is between the -ing phrase and the main clause:

1. John lived on takeaway food -- regularly discarding the packaging on the floor.

This -ing phrase does not look like a description of cause or consequence, as in "Feeling hungry (= Because he was hungry), John bought a sandwich" and "The typhoon struck the city, killing fifty people (=, which killed five people)."

How would you describe the relation of the -ing phrase to the main clause in (1)?

Comment: _Sequential_ or _simultaneous_, if I had to settle on just one word.

Comment: Can you say "He lived on takeaway food while regularly discarding the packaging on the floor"?

Comment: The expression _regularly discarding the packaging on the floor_ is an adjunct, an optional item in clause structure. It refers to the subject "John", so it's predicative; not a complement, though, but an adjunct, more precisely a "depictive adjunct". Adjuncts like this one are often called "supplements", since they are not tightly integrated into clause structure, but are loosely attached in writing by punctuation like a comma or dash, and set apart in speech by a slight pause.

Comment: I'm more concerned about its semantic aspects. What exactly does it relate to the main clause semantically? What semantic function does it serve there?

Comment: BillJ just explained. It's a separate predication that is asserted alongside the main clause, and its precise semantics depends on what it is and what the main clause is. In this case, consuming and discarding are in opposition (you can do one or the other to anything, but not both), so the clauses can be connected in any way that asserts or presupposes a conjunction of the two propositions. This may include temporal _while_, certainly; and if you don't need to use a participle, you could just say _He lived on junk food and threw the packages on the floor_.

Comment: It's giving  descriptive information about "John".

Comment: Can you move "regularly discarding the packaging on the floor" right after "John", as in "John, regularly discarding the packaging on the floor, lived on takeaway food"?

Comment: Yes, that works. _Discarding_ works just like your examples of _feeling hungry_ or _killing people_.

Comment: One thing I'm concerned about is the relation to the main clause; my other examples are clear with the -ing phrases. They indicate either cause, consequence, or simultaneity (the latter as demonstrated in "He sat there smiling.") But such relation does not exist in the original example. If it were "John lived on takeaway food, finding it inconvenient to cook at home", the relation  would be far more explicit.